# Search in Array and get specific string value

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have a Wordpress post meta that has multiple arrays like this.

```
$costdata = Array(
    Array( 'cost_id' => 1, 'cost_category' => 'Travel', 'cost_amount' => '3540')
    Array( 'cost_id' => 2, 'cost_category' => 'Materials', 'cost_amount' => '1644')
    Array( 'cost_id' => 3, 'cost_category' => 'Travel', 'cost_amount' => '1800')
);
add_post_meta($project_id, 'costdata', $costdata);
```

What I want to do is to get all `'cost_amount'` where `'cost_category'` is "Travel"

This is what I've done so far. I get a blank value. No error.

```
$listtravelcost = get_post_meta($project_id, 'costdata');

/*Calculate Travel cost */
$found_Travel = array_search('Travel', array_column($listtravelcost, 'cost_category'));

$travelbudget = array_column($found_Travel, 'cost_amount');
$printtravelbudget = array_sum($travelbudget);
echo $printtravelbudget;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `array_search`, you should use `array_filter`. `array_search` will only return the first element it finds that is equal to your needle. `array_filter` will return all entries in an array, for which the function returns `true`.

```
$found_Travel = array_filter($listtravelcost, function($entry)  {
    return $entry['cost_category'] === 'Travel';
});
```

The rest of your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use loop:

```
$travelbudget = [];
foreach ($costdata as $arr) {
    if ($arr['cost_category'] === "Travel") {
        $travelbudget[] = $arr;
    }
}
```